# $templateCache to fancybox, how to bind variables to controller scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, fancybox, angularjs-scope

I have been struggling for a coupe of hours trying to get fancybox to display html template from `$templateCache`. It all works fine except for the annoying fact the the data binding does not work and I'm not sure how to solve it.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{ templateVariable }}!

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="testTemplate.html">
        <h1>{{ templateVariable }}</h1>
        <p>Bla bla bla</p>
    </script>

    <br /><br />
    <a href="#" show-template>Show template</a>
</div>
```

---

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('showTemplate', function($templateCache, $compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                var template = $templateCache.get('testTemplate.html');
                var compiled = $compile(template)(scope);
                $.fancybox.open(template);
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.templateVariable = 'My template variable';
});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/oligustafsson/p4f7mh19/

Anyone have any insights to how to accomplish this feat?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, this is what I came up with:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Hello, {{ templateVariable }}!

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="testTemplate.html">
        <div>
            <h1>{{ templateVariable }}</h1>
            <p>Bla bla bla</p>
            <div>Mooo</div>
        </div>
    </script>

    <br /><br />
    <a href="#" show-template="">Show template</a>
</div>
```

I wrapped the template html in a div.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('showTemplate', function($templateCache, $compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                $timeout( function(){
                    var template = $templateCache.get('testTemplate.html');
                    var linkFn = $compile(template);
                    var linkedContent = linkFn(scope);
                    $.fancybox.open(linkedContent);
                }, 0)
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.templateVariable = 'My template variable';
});
```

Finding some other suggestions like using $timeout and $compile, this seems to work just fine.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oligustafsson/vpbutty0/

Thanx!